# py2exe File "numpy\core\multiarray.pyc", line 10, in __load ImportError: DLL load failed:

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, 64-bit, py2exe

**System:**

Windows 7 64-bit

Anaconda 2.7 64-bit

py2exe 64-bit

**Background:**

I converted my python code to .exe using py2exe and setup.py file shown below:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

from distutils.filelist import findall
import matplotlib

opts = {"py2exe": {
    "packages" : ['matplotlib'],
    "includes": ['scipy', 'scipy.integrate', 'scipy.special.*','scipy.linalg.*'],
         'dll_excludes': ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                            'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
            'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll']
                     }
           }

setup(
      windows = [{'script': "with_GUI.py"}], zipfile = None,
      options= opts,
      data_files = matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()
     )
```

But this gave me some error saying that there was version conflict with two files. So I changed the two files viz. dist/tcl/tcl8.5/init.tcl (in line 19) and dist/tcl/tk8.5/tk.tcl (in line 18). In my case I changed the version from 8.5.15 to 8.5.18. I found the location of the two files by looking at the path specified by the error in error log. Then the .exe worked just fine.

**Problem:**

I zipped the dist folder which contains .exe file. Then, I unzipped it on another computer but it is not working there. Following is the error it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Moment_Final.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 122, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\cbook.pyc", line 33, in <module>
  File "numpy\__init__.pyc", line 180, in <module>
  File "numpy\add_newdocs.pyc", line 13, in <module>
  File "numpy\lib\__init__.pyc", line 8, in <module>
  File "numpy\lib\type_check.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "numpy\core\__init__.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "numpy\core\multiarray.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "numpy\core\multiarray.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**Update:**
If I install Anaconda Python 2.7 on the system, there is no error. But then, what is the use of py2exe.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue. The solution has been found on the link below :

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.py2exe/4847

In short, two dlls from "C:\Anaconda2\Library\bin" were missing in the "dist" output of py2exe.

Comment: Actually, in the end it worked after I copied all the DLL's in the C:\Anaconda2\Library\bin to the dist folder.

Comment: For my case, it's the libiomp5md.dll, and the mkl_*.dll